# cshtml file variable and multiple classes per tag not rendering properly

Tags: c#, razor

Unfortunately, with key words like "class", it's extremely difficult to locate the answer to this question.

What I want: `<tr class="collapse multi-collapse">`, but what I'm getting is `<tr class="collapse" multi-collapse="">`

How this is happening:

```
    var st = "collapse multi-collapse";
    style = $"class={st}";
    <tr @style>
```

The reason I'm putting the two items in a single variable is because I thought it would render the two together instead of separating them...but that didn't work, as you can see. I originally just had the two values in there directly, but that didn't work, either.

Why this is happening or what I can do to get what I'm looking for...I just don't know. How do I make this render the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [this post][1], I realized that the variable can't include `class=`. So I changed the `<tr>` tag to look like this instead: `<tr class="@style">` and made sure that the `style` variable looks like this: `style = $"{st}";` and then everything rendered properly.

```
    var st = "collapse multi-collapse";
    style = $"{st}";
    <tr class="@style">

  [1]: https://newbedev.com/how-to-add-a-second-css-class-with-a-conditional-value-in-razor-mvc-4
```